# How to move files from svn folder to production server

Tags: production-environment

I have a website written in PHP under source control (SVN). I would like to move at once all my files from the website directory to production server.

The problem is that in this folder there are folders of SVN (.svn). The second problem is that i do not want to put on the server only files under source control, but also other in this folder (images, css, and so on).

Could you please tell me how to do this? It would be nice if it would be repeatable - that so I would have only one command to execute.

And if there would be any possibility to optimize uploading (not uploading not changed files) to make whole process of going production faster would be nice too.

EDIT:

My development environment is  Eclipse PDT and favorite FTP filezilla.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the export function of subversion, this will allow you to export all files under version control, but also all files NOT under control. Both methods will skip the .svn folders.

You didn't mention your client, but Tortoise has the 'export unversioned files too' option.

See [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html) for commandline syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ftp client if it's support filters (exclude .svn folders, i.e FlashFXP).

Currently I'm using Nusphere PhpEd IDE's built in feature called "Smart upload", so it only updates changed files (with modified time changed).

Answer (score 1):

I use [rsync](http://samba.org/rsync/) which is a fast command line tool which only sends the changed parts of files.  You can set it up to exclude .svn directories as outlined [here](http://blog.gungfu.de/archives/2005/09/25/using-rsync-together-with-subversion/):

If you wish to continue doing this with fileZilla you can go to View->Filename Filters and select to ignore SVN and CVS directories.  You can also only upload changed files with FileZilla however I find rsync far faster.  As rsync is command line based you could easily hook it up with Eclipse as an external tool to enable 1 click transferring

Answer (score 1):

You can use springloops, they cover SVN commit and checkouts but most importantly deployment to FTP server with a click of a mouse...

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled recently on the same issue running Ubuntu 9.
In FileZilla you can choose ignore filters which contain even presets to prevent copying .svn folders and windows .thumb files!  You can find this in the **View** menu under **Filename filters...**  Works like a charm!

Thumbs up for the FileZilla folks!